Check Map value, wait if need and update atomically
I'm looking for an easy to understand atomic replacement for the code snippet below. Or an algorithm on how to do it correctly.
Let's assume there is a map:
// key->number of resources occupied
Map<Long, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


Several tasks are executed in different threads.
Each task checks whether resources are available before execution. If not, it waits until they are released by another task, otherwise it updates the counter, thereby temporarily taking the necessary resources for itself. This code fragment must be executed atomically.
After the necessary calculations, the task "releases" the resources and decrements the counter.

private void do(long key, int count) {
        // must be atomic code
        while (map.get(key) + count > 25) {
            sleep(100);
        }
        map.put(key, map.get(key) + count);
        // must be atomic code

        // do some computations

        // atomic analog of map.put(key, map.get(key) - count);
        map.merge(key, count, (current, next) -> current - next);
}

I experimented with ConcurrentHashMap methods, specifically tried to sleep in the merge method, but the code hangs at the moment of executing the final code string map.merge(key, count, (current, next) -> current - next).
Example of code:
map.merge(key, count, (current, next) -> {
      while (current + next > 25) {
          sleep(100);
          current = map.get(key);
      }

       return current + next;
   }
);

EDIT1
I tried the Semaphore class. Please comment if I am using it correctly?
Map<Long, Semaphore> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private void do(long key, int count) {
        Semaphore semaphore = map.computeIfAbsent(key, s -> new Semaphore(5));
        semaphore.acquire(count);

        try {
            // do some computations

            semaphore.release(count);
        } finally {
            semaphore.release(intervals.size());
        }
}


You can probably use something from the java.util.concurrent package - possibly Semaphore.

I tried the Semaphore class. Please comment if I am using it correctly? I don't think so.  Since the Semaphore is created new each time, no other thread can see it, so how does it protect anything?  You need some sort of global/shared state that all threads can use to synchronize on for this to work.

No, the semaphore is created only once for each key. I wrote a test, looked at System.identityHashCode(semaphore) - the same value in all threads

Using sleep() in concurrent code seems like a code smell.

Use -> new Semaphore(1) for one permit per key, and then have semaphore.acquire(); try{ with } finally {semaphore.release();} around the critical section.

in this simple example only one thread can be executing the critical section because we use Semaphore with one permit Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1)
Let's use the semaphore:
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
     
    public class Program {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         
        Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1); // 1 permit 
        CommonResource res = new CommonResource();
        new Thread(new CountThread(res, sem, "CountThread 1")).start();
        new Thread(new CountThread(res, sem, "CountThread 2")).start();
        new Thread(new CountThread(res, sem, "CountThread 3")).start();
    }
}
class CommonResource{
     
    int x=0;  
}
 
class CountThread implements Runnable{
 
    CommonResource res;
    Semaphore sem;
    String name;
    CountThread(CommonResource res, Semaphore sem, String name){
        this.res=res;
        this.sem=sem;
        this.name=name;
    }
      
    public void run(){
         
        try{
            System.out.println(name + " wait permit");
            sem.acquire(); //here start critical section add your logic below
            res.x=1;
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++){  
                System.out.println(this.name + ": " + res.x);
                res.x++;
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
        System.out.println(name + " release permit");
        sem.release();
    }
}

console output:
    CountThread 1 wait permit
    CountThread 2 wait permit
    CountThread 3 wait permit
    CountThread 1: 1
    CountThread 1: 2
    CountThread 1: 3
    CountThread 1: 4
    CountThread 1 release permit
    CountThread 3: 1
    CountThread 3: 2
    CountThread 3: 3
    CountThread 3: 4
    CountThread 3 release permit
    CountThread 2: 1
    CountThread 2: 2
    CountThread 2: 3
    CountThread 2: 4
    CountThread 2 release permit


Your code have a little problem's...
Let's review your method:
private void do( long key, int count ) {  
    if( map.get( key ) + count > 25 ) {
        // this line, which seems to put the thread to sleep, is omitted 
        // when the condition is not satisfied, which causes an 
        // infinite loop
        sleep( 100 );
    } 
    else {             
         // the “merge” method is used to simplify the update of a map,
         // if the key does not exist, it adds the pair “key, value”, 
         // and if it exists, it modifies the value assigned to the key, 
         // using the expression passed as a parameter. 
         // therefore the line is unnecessary
        map.put( key, map.get( key ) + count );
    }
      // as it is outside the "else", it is executed even without having
      // a new entry, and if I rely on the previous sentence, what you need 
      // to do is to add the current value to the new one.
    map.merge( key, count, ( current, next ) -> current - next );
}

revised method:
private void do( long key, int count ) { 
    if( map.get( key ) + count <= 25 ) {
        map.merge( key, count, (current, next) -> current + next );
    }
    else {
        sleep( 100 );
    }
}


Yes, thanks. I just noticed that when I simplified the code, I made a mistake. I'll edit it now. In any case, this is an example of non-atomic code, it looks like the advice with Semaphores works.

totally agree, the main question was answered by Valery (mark it as accepted), that's why I only addressed the errors in your code, not knowing that they were of “adaptation”, answer removed in 3, 2, 1, ...
